# Eclipse console which print cmd output cause encoding problem

Tags: eclipse, encoding

Eclipse terminal shows weird character with bat file execution

[image]

In the picture with Eclipse console output, Some of Eclipse console character cracked

I know I can change encoding in debug > preference > common page and none of these encoding showed well. (MS949, UTF-8, ASCI2) Especially, carriage return character was cracked.

I want to print console output as much as same as cmd output.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Pipe the output in another program that removes all `\r` characters and prints them to `stdout`.

Comment: Or maybe it is anough to append `cmd /C ` before the command.

Comment: When I removes all \r characters in linux, but cmd ouput makes '\r' automatically

Comment: cmd /C doesn't worked for me :( Thank you giving some idea!

Comment: Those look like [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) for controlling the console - the Eclipse console doesn't support them.